# Background-position not working with CSS animation and linear gradient

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I'm attempting to use CSS3 (gradients and animations) to make an animation similar to the iphone slide to unlock gradient.  However, for some reason, the background-position only works when I use static pixel numbers and not when I use percentages.  Ideally, I'd be able to apply this class to any element, and have the animation work, without needing to code for specific widths.  Can somebody point me in the right direction?

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ekLamtbL/

```
.slideToUnlock {
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, black 0%, gray 40%, white 45%, gray 55%, black 60%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
    -webkit-animation: slidetounlock 5s infinite;
    animation: slidetounlock 5s infinite;
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
    animation-direction: normal;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slidetounlock {
  0% {
    background-position: -100% 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 100% 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Consider using viewport width instead of percentage? (100vw)

Comment: @EoghanTadhg for the background percentage or the gradient?

Comment: Placed it on the background position: https://jsfiddle.net/7wLtzvLr/
Perhaps I misunderstood.

Comment: That makes it loop quite a bit.  Ideally, it would move one full width across, then start over at the beginning

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Added your code

```
background-size: 250% 250%;
```

Example

```
.slideToUnlock {
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, black 0%, gray 40%, white 45%, gray 55%, black 60%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-animation: slidetounlock 5s infinite;
  animation: slidetounlock 5s infinite;
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
  animation-direction: normal;
  background-size: 250% 250%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ekLamtbL/2/

Comment: Can you explain why background-size: 250% 250%; works here?

Comment: @isevcik Lutymane actually answers it in their answer.

Answer (score 3):

[Article on MDN explains it well](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position#regarding_percentages)

tldr:
To make a use of percentage `background-position` your background's size should not equal to `100%` of the dimension you want to position. `N%` position means `N%` of the background is mapped to `N%` of the element. Since gradient automatically has size of `100%x100%` setting `background-position` seem to have no effect unless you set `background-size` to some value like `200%` for example